# How to have varnish-modules installed on 20.04

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, ppa, varnish

The source is at https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules but I couldn't build it.

Ideally I'd want something installable through a `ppa`. The closest I could get was [https://launchpad.net/~lasse-karstensen/+archive/ubuntu/varnish-modules](https://launchpad.net/%7Elasse-karstensen/+archive/ubuntu/varnish-modules) but this is old and doesn't have support for 20 (only for 18).

I'd also be OK to install it from a `.deb` or `.rpm` file if one exists and is possible.

Comment: Did you try to install them - in a VM eventually? Sometimes packages for older versions work on newer versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: You could also download them manually from [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org), for instance Debian Sid branch to get the latest.

Answer (score 0):

You can install latest available varnish modules deb package (Built on 22-07-2020) by executing below commands in terminal.

```
wget -c 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/varnish-modules/varnish-modules_0.16.0-2_amd64.deb'

sudo dpkg -i varnish-modules_0.16.0-2_amd64.deb
```

Fix missing dependencies.

```
sudo apt install -f
```

In case it future it new version is available, you can find latest package by vising link [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/varnish-modules/).

Comment: Thanks. It's giving me `varnish-modules depends on varnishabi-11.0; however Package varnishabi-11.0 is not installed.` though, and I cannot find where from to install that `varnishabi` package.

Comment: Can you give whole output ?

Comment: You should be able to find depedencies here http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/varnish/

Comment: Full output: https://pastebin.com/raw/5utsh1Qr

I can't find that `varnishabi` dependency on `universe/v/varnish`.